# Not able to retrieve multiple variables from a function

Tags: php, list, function, return

Hi I am trying to use the list() function to retrieve two variables from within a function. The function returns the to variables within an array.

```
function thumb_dimensions($case, $image_width, $image_height){
    switch($case){
        case 1:
            $thumb_width    =   100;
            $thumb_height   =   100;
        break;
        case 2:
            $thumb_height   =   100;
            $ratio          =   $thumb_height / $image_height;
            $thumb_width    =   round( $image_width * $ratio );
        break;
        case 3:
            $thumb_width    =   100;
            $ratio          =   $thumb_width / $image_width;
            $thumb_height   =   round($image_height * $ratio);
        break;


        return array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
    }


}

$case = 3;
list($thumb_width, $thumb_height) = thumb_dimensions($case, $image_width, $image_height);
```

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump(thumb_dimensions($case, $image_width, $image_height))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` statement is inside the switch but after the `break`, so it doesn't run. Your function doesn't return anything and the `list` fails.

Move the `return` statement out of the switch and it should be fine.